# JSS/NextJS: how to disable SSL cert validation via ProxyConfig.proxyOptions.secure setting

Tags: jss, nextjs

I'm running in connected mode on my local and I want to disable SSL cert validation. According to the [Sitecore docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--rendering-a-jss-app-server-side-using-the-headless-jss-proxy.html), this option is mentioned:

> ... in the SSR application jss-proxy-ssr, in the config.js file, in the proxyOptions object, you can disable SSL validation entirely by setting the secure to false option. For example:

```json
proxyOptions: {

  // Setting this to false will disable SSL certificate validation
  // when proxying to a SSL Sitecore instance.
  // This is a major security issue, so NEVER EVER set this to false
  // outside local development. Use a real CA-issued certificate.
  // NEVER EVER do this in production. It will make your SSL completely insecure.
  
  secure: false
}
```

It's not clear how to actually do this. I started by [searching for](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/search?q=proxyOptions) `proxyOptions` in the JSS repo. I looked into making the change in `bootstrap.ts` via the `configOverride` var, but it's only a simple list of key value pairs which doesn't appear to support tunnelling into `ProxyConfig.proxyOptions.secure`:

```
const configOverride: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

Comment: What is the use case here? The Next.js/JSS doesn't proxy the CD's like React/Angular/Vue+JSS does. Are you trying use http for the GraphQL service call?

Comment: I'm running this via `npm run start:connected` which corresponds to script `npm-run-all --serial bootstrap --parallel next:dev start:watch-components`. The use case is that I want to avoid uploading the certificate in the node store. Experience editor is running on `https://sitecore10u2.sc` and the front end is running on `http://localhost:3000`. I have `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`, as recommended here (https://getfishtank.ca/blog/next-build-certificate-error-sitecore), but I still experience SSL issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProxyConfig.proxyOptions.secure` setting likely isn't applicable in this case because there is no proxy involved. Also, as the docs state, disabling SSL isn't a great practice.

Instead of trying to disable SSL validation to fix my issues, I opted to make SSL validation work by adding my SIF Trusted Root certificate to Node. In short:

`setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS C:\some\path\to\my-shiny-sif-certificate.cer`

Sitecore has a solid guide:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--configuring-sitecore-ca-certificates-for-node-js.html

I also wrote a bit more about this subject:

https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/nextjs-unable-verify-first-certificate